# How can I add an unlimited set of integers in Python given by the user?

Tags: python, list

The problem I am working on should:

- read a set of integers (from user) and store them in list
- compute the sum of all the numbers in said list and output it to the user
- use lists and functions
- gives an error message and exits if user enters anything but a number
- user enters 0 to quit

Sample output:

```
Please enter a number: 1

Please enter a number: 5

Please enter a number: 6

Please enter a number: 7

Please enter a number: 8

Please enter a number: 0

1 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 = 27
```

My current code, which isn't complete yet:

```
def createList():
    myList = []
    return myList

def fillList(myList):    
    number = int(input("Please enter a number: "))

    while number != 0:
        myList.append(number)
        number = int(input("Please enter a number: "))

def printList(myList):
    for number in myList:
        print(number, "+")

def main():
    myList = createList()
    fillList(myList)
    printList(myList)

main()
```

In addition, I don't understand how to have the numbers, that the user inputs, show up with a '+' in between each one and an equal sign at the end.

**Updated code... I still need to figure out a way to include an error message if user types anything other than an integer. Also, user presses 0 to quit:**

```
def createList():
   myList = []
   return myList

def fillList(myList):    
    number = int(input("Please enter a number: "))

    while number != 0:
        myList.append(number)
        number = int(input("Please enter a number: "))

def printList(myList):
        print(' + '.join(map(str, myList)), end = ' = ')
        print(sum(myList))

def main():
    myList = createList()
    fillList(myList)
    printList(myList)

main()
```

Comment: If you want to do this in a loop, you need some kind of special code to either (a) insert a `+` before each element unless it's the first one, or (b) insert a `+` after each element unless it's the last one. Once you recognize that there's no way around that, it becomes pretty easy to write, if a bit clumsy. (But, of course, there _is_ a way around that once you realize you don't need to write a loop in the first place, and can just use `join`, as in chrisaycock's answer.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More easier to do.

```
temp = input()
my_list = []

while(True):
        if temp.isdigit():
                temp = int(temp)
                if temp == 0:
                        break
                my_list.append(temp)
                temp = input()
        else:
                raise Exception('Invalid Input')

print(' + '.join(map(str,my_list)),end = ' = ')
print(sum(my_list))
```

Comment: Where would I then include the prompt: Please enter a number: ?

Comment: Inside the input()

Comment: When I run the code and test it by using a letter, I am getting an error message (not invalid input), but from Python itself. `line 12, in <module>
    raise Exception('Invalid Input')
Exception: Invalid Input`

Comment: That's because you cannot add alphabets. In your question, you said integers not alphabets

Comment: I wanted to include an error message if the user inputs anything other than a number

Comment: Use `ValueError('Invalid Input')` instead of the exception

Comment: Still having issues when I run it- when I test it by entering a letter it doesn't give the invalid input message. `number = input("Please enter a number: ")
myList = []
    
while(True):
    if number.isdigit():
        number = int(number)
        if number == 0:
            break
        myList.append(number)
        number = input("Please enter a number: ")
    else:
        ValueError("Invalid Input")

print(' + '.join(map(str, myList)), end = ' = ')
print(sum(myList))`

Comment: It gives the message along with expection. If you don't want the exception, then better replace the `ValueError` or `Exception` with a print statement followed by an exit statement.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of printing in a loop like you've done, just `join` the inputs (and be sure to convert to `str` first).

```
In [11]: myList = [1, 2, 3]

In [12]: print(' + '.join(map(str, myList)))
1 + 2 + 3
```

Comment: I am confused on the 'In [11].... In [12]'. Where did you get those numbers? Or were you just giving an example? Are you allocating this bit of code to 'def printList' ?

Comment: @Bunny The `In` stuff is IPython's prompt; it's equivalent to `>>>` in the regular Python REPL. I set `myList` as an example in the first line so we could look at the output in the second line. And yes, you can put that new `print` statement in your function definition.

Comment: So would the `myList[1, 2, 3]` actually be empty... `myList[]`, since the user will need to input and it would be unlimited, I can't guess how many numbers they will be entering.

Comment: @Bunny Your list would start off is empty, correct. Again, I just pre-set the list as an example.

Comment: I updated my OP, however, when I run it, it is printing the output three times. I'm not sure why? And thank you for all your help!

Comment: @Bunny Don't use a loop. Just have the two print statements in your function.

Comment: Gotcha! So, where would I implement the error message if user enters something other than a number? Under `def fillList` ? Would I still use the `while number != 0` ?